# jquery function call isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

That's the code. The problem is the `this.play` call to start the function `play()` is always reporting an error. I tried a few different variations but none work.

```js
[...]
event_listeners() {
  var result;
  $(document).on('keypress', function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 49) {
      result = 1;
    } else if (evt.which == 50) {
      result = 2;
    } else if (evt.which == 51) {
      result = 3;
    } else if (evt.which == 52) {
      result = 4;
    } else if (evt.which == 53) {
      result = 5;
    } else if (evt.which == 54) {
      result = 6;
    } else if (evt.which == 55) {
      result = 7;
    }
    console.log(result);
    this.play(result);
  });
}

play(column) {
    console.log('play methode' + column);
    var movecount = 0;

    availableRow = this._model.checkAvailableRow(column);

    if (availableRow === -1) {
      $('.won').text("Fehler! Spalte voll!");
      return;
    }
    // Inkrementieren der Variablen, da checkAvailableRow() die Nummer der Zeile zurückgibt, hier aber der Arrayindex benötigt wird
    availableRow++;

    if (this.checkWin() == true) {
      $('.won').html((currentPlayer === "Player 1" ? "Player 1" : "Player 2") + " gewinnt!");
    }
    if (movecount === 41) {
      $('.won').html('Unentschieden!');
    }
    // Wechsel zum anderen Spieler
    this.switchTurn();
    movecount++;
  }
  [...]
```

When executed this error is shown in the console.

> View.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: this.play is not a function

What am I doing wrong when I want to start the `play()` function?

Comment: Just use `play(result);`

Comment: `this` is not what you think, it is probably equal to `window`.
Bind `this` to your event listener or don't use it ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2):

`play` function is outside of the scope and for this reason, it is not available inside the context of the keypress event. Using `this` refers the scope where the function is executed (global scope).

Using only `play(result)` will solve the issue.

For more information about `this`, you can have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)